# unable to bind event while passing component props to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code(pasted below), where I'm trying to bind the 'id' to onChange event to pass it to parent component.

Problem: `onChange={this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)}` returns error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

while if I replace `this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)` to `this.markComplete.bind(this, id)`, there is no error. I am kind of lost where I am doing wrong.

Note: Other than the 'bind', the passing props is working as expected.

Code:

```
export class Tasks extends Component {
  getStyle = () => {
    return {
      textDecoration: this.props.todo.completed ? "line-through" : "none"
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { id, title } = this.props.todo;
    return (
      <div style={this.getStyle()}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="task"
          checked={this.props.todo.completed ? true : null}
          onChange={this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)}
        />
        <label>{title}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tasks;
```

Comment: Try `() => this.props.markComplete && this.props.markComplete(id)` instead. If `onChange` is not passed, it will break at compile time

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Thats just straight up wrong. You are calling function not passing reference

Comment: where you have defined `markComplete` ? can you share the parent component where you are sending the props.

Comment: @Rajesh, your suggestions worked, Thanks!!

Comment: @Adnomination Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply call `markComplete` passed through props without `.bind`-ing:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const taskList = [
  {id:0, title: 'Do something', completed: false},
  {id:1, title: 'Do something else', completed: false},
  {id:2, title: 'Do some other stuff', completed: true},
]      

class Task extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, completed } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor:this.props.completed ? 'green' : 'none'}}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="task"
          checked={completed}
          onChange={() => this.props.markComplete(id)}
        />
        <label>{title}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TaskBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {tasks:this.props.tasks}
    this.handleComplete = this.handleComplete.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleComplete(taskId, completed){
    const tasks = [...this.state.tasks],
          completedTask = tasks.find(({id}) => id == taskId)
    completedTask.completed = true
    this.setState({tasks})
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      this.state.tasks.map(task => <Task {...{key:task.id, markComplete:this.handleComplete,...task}} />)
    )
  }
}

render(<TaskBoard tasks={taskList} />, rootNode)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For a newbie, there is so much to learn. I will test out your suggestion and will respond back, albeit with questions :-)

Comment: @Adnomination : You're quite welcome. Just note, since you didn't left the way to *un-complete* the task in your code, I didn't either, however, it can be done with slight tweak

Comment: I have to give you that you quite well understood what was happening in parent component without me explaining anything about that. It worked as you mentioned without binding. But do you have idea why bind didn't work on my code?

Comment: @Adnomination : Without knowing the rest of the code context, I'd suspect, you attempted to call `markComplete()` without actually passing it as a prop for your child component (hence, the error you've seen). But even if you would, you'd probably face another problem, as your code was attempting to assign the value, returned by `markComplete()` to `onChange` event handler, whereas, you were supposed to ***trigger*** executing that callback, passed through props.

Comment: There is actually a main component App which is being called on index, and then four other components. So I am passing `markComplete(id)` as props through each component to the App component. On App component I have a State with the todos, and `onChange`, Task component is passing `id` to the App component where I have a function `markCompleted` which will change the state of todo:completed to true.

Comment: @Adnomination : What you described above (passing props through multiple components)  is the thing you should definitely avoid. I recommend you to have a look at [React Contex](https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)t or (if you're doing such thing multiple times across your app with state passed back and forth between scattered components) state management tools, like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/). Those should make your app much easier to develop and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind the function in this place.

As I can understand from your code, you have another Component and you're passing the `markComplete` function as props to `Tasks` Component, right?

You probably have something like this:

```
export class AnotherComponent extends Component {
  markComplete(id) {
    // doSomething
  }

  render() {
    <Tasks todo={someTodoObject} markComplete={this.markComplete} />
  }
}
```

You need to bind the `markComplete` function in this parent Component (or use arrow function), e.g:

```
export class AnotherComponent extends Component {
  // Example using bind
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.markComplete = this.markComplete.bind(this)
  }

  markComplete(id) {
    // doSomething
  }

  render() {
    <Tasks todo={someTodoObject} markComplete={this.markComplete} />
  }
}
```

or

```
export class AnotherComponent extends Component {
  // Example using arrow function
  markComplete = (id) => {
    // doSomething
  }

  render() {
    <Tasks todo={someTodoObject} markComplete={this.markComplete} />
  }
}
```

This way you bind the function to the Component where your state is.

Also, on the `Tasks` Component (let's say you're not using .bind there anymore), in your case, you can't use the `onChange` like that:

`onChange={this.props.markComplete(this, id)}`

This will call the `markComplete` function as soon as it is rendered.

If you have a function that needs to be executed after some event *(click, change, etc)* and this function receives a parameter, you always need to do something like:

`onChange={() => this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)}`

So you create a function that will call your function.
Otherwise you are already calling the function.

*Hope I was clear about it! It's kinda confusing*

Comment: It's not confusing but well explained. I will test this out and will respond back to you as well. Love to learn different aspect of doing one thing. Thanks!!